# Zend 2 conditional validator

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I am struggling with performing a validation problem, based on a field entity called `published` I must apply validation rules:

- Validate entity when it is set to `true`
- Do nothing when it is set to `false` (draft feature)

I managed to add a callback validator to canonical fields which check my rule and it works 
fine:

```
Validator definition
    $emptyValidatorOnPublish = array(
        'name' => 'Callback',
        'options' => array(
            'messages' => array(
                \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'This field cannot be empty',
            ),
            'callback' => function($value, $context=array()) {
                if($context['published']){//Here I know the POST value
                    return !empty($value); //it must not be empty
                }
                return true;
            },
        ),
    );
```

Usage:

```
 array(
    'name' => 'title',
    'description' => 'Title of the interview',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'Zend\\Filter\\StringTrim',
            'options' => array()
        ),
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'Zend\\Filter\\StripTags',
            'options' => array()
        )
    ),
    'validators' => array($emptyValidatorOnPublish),
    'error_message' => 'title is required',
    'allow_empty' => true,
    'continue_if_empty' => true
)
```

Now I have on some fields which are validated with a `ObjectExists` validator:

```
array(
    'name' => 'person',
    'description' => 'Person link',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(),
    'validators' => array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'MyApp\\Validators\\ObjectExists',
            'options' => array(
                'fields' => 'ref',
                'message' => 'This person does not exist',
                'object_manager' => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
                'object_repository' => 'MyApp\\Person'
            )
        )
    ),
    'allow_empty' => true,
    'continue_if_empty' => true
),
```

The `ObjectExists` validator extends `DoctrineModule\Validator\ObjectExists`.

```
class ObjectExists extends BaseObjectExists
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        if (! is_array($value)) {
            return parent::isValid($value);
        }

        $isValid = null;

        foreach ($value as $oneValue) {
            $isValid = false === $isValid ? $isValid : parent::isValid($oneValue);
        }

        return $isValid;
    }
}
```

Problem:

- The parent class validator doesn't know the value of `published`
- Even if I change the implementation to check the `published` value I will get the value from the DB not from the actual `POST` request

Is there a way to check the existence of an entity depending on the `published` value from the request?

Is there a way to pass a sibling value when validating another field (in my case pass `'published` when validating a `person`)?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but is the problem that you don't have `$context` inside the `isValid` method of your `ObjectExists` validator?

Comment: Hello Wilt, when a user sets the entity to published I need to validate fields (not by the data retrieved in the db but from the request). Found a solution though, don't know how ok it is :D

Answer (score 3):

Your input-filter has something called a [validation group](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html). You could remove the input that you don't want to validate from that validator group when the value for your `published` field is `false` and then those input elements don't get validated when the input-filter is running.

You don't have to solve this in the validator class itself. It would be better to move this logic to a higher level (so example by setting the validation group inside the `init` method of your input-filter class). I don't think the validator class itself should be handling this responsibility.

```
//pass the input names you want to validate here when published is false
if($published === false){
    $inputFilter->setValidationGroup();
}
```

In such a solution you only have to inject this `published` field inside your input-filter class and not inside all the individual validators.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I am using config based validations and apigility asks what validations I want for GET,POST,PATCH and DELETE (or global)

Comment: You could still implement this also when using Apigility.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

1. Create a factory for the validator in which you inject the request parameters:

> ```
> class ObjectExistsIfPublishedFactory implements FactoryInterface,MutableCreationOptionsInterface 
> {
>     /**
>      * @var array
>      */
>     protected $options = array();
>
>   public function setCreationOptions(array $options)
>   {
>       $this->options = $options;
>   }
>
>   public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
>   {
>       $services = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
>       $application = $services->get('Application');
>       $mvcEvent  = $application->getMvcEvent();
>       $dataContainer = $mvcEvent->getParam('ZFContentNegotiationParameterData', false);
>       $data = $dataContainer->getBodyParams(); //Get request parameters
>       $this->options['isPublished'] = $data['published']?true:false; //Add to the options of the validator
>       $objectManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get($this->options['object_manager']);
>
>       $this->options['object_repository'] = $objectManager->getRepository($this->options['object_repository']);
>       return new ObjectExistsIfPublished($this->options);
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Use the injected request variable when validationg:

> ```
> use DoctrineModule\Validator\ObjectExists as BaseObjectExists;
> class ObjectExistsIfPublished extends BaseObjectExists
> {
>
>     /**
>      * {@inheritDoc}
>      */
>     public function isValid($value)
>     {
>         $isValid = true;
>         if($this->getOption('isPublished')){
>             if (! is_array($value)) {
>                 return parent::isValid($value);
>             }
>             $isValid = null;
>             foreach ($value as $oneValue) {
>                 $isValid = false === $isValid ? $isValid : parent::isValid($oneValue);
>             }
>         }
>         return $isValid;
>     }
> }
> ```